# Forge Viewer Properties Drop Down

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu that is populated by a distinct list of all the property names in a model/multiple models that are in the forge viewer.

is the best way to

1 . get bulk properties
2. filter to just get the name of the properties
3. create a unique array o values from that

or is there a simpler way of doing this ? it seems like there should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more efficient way would be to use the [executeUserFunction](https://forge.autodesk.com/ja/node/1390) to run a custom piece of code in the property database web worker, and collect all property names from there, e.g., like this:

```js
async function getPropertyNames(model) {
    function userFunction(pdb) {
        let propertyNames = [];
        pdb.enumAttributes(function (attrId, attrDef) {
            propertyNames.push(attrDef.name);
        });
        return propertyNames;
    }
    return await model.getPropertyDb().executeUserFunction(userFunction);
}
```